# Issue with Response.TransmitFile

Tags: debugging, download, response.write, event-viewer

I have been working on an issue for the past 2 days.I have tried to debug in every way possible but in vain.
Everything works fine on my local.But on production this fails.
Here is a brief description about the problem.
I have a download button and when I click that button I intend to download a file from a server.

protected void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    Button downloadButton = sender as Button;
    string filePath = downloadButton.CommandArgument;       

     string stuid = Session["browse_files_for_student"].ToString();
    string stuUsername = MyHelper.GetUsernameForStudentID(stuid);
    MyHelper.LogAccess(User.Identity.Name, StudentUsername.Text, filePath, MyHelper.LogAccessType.Read); 
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

    // Download the file
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
    try
    {
        Response.TransmitFile(filePath);           
    }
    catch (IOException error)
    {
         Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("global_last_error", "The file is in use by another process."));
        Response.Redirect("~/Public/KnownError.aspx");
    }
    Response.End();

}
```

I see on the Event Viewer that it generates:
TransmitFile failed:FileName:dsdfsfd.doc,Impersonation Enabled:0,Token Valid:1 HRESULT:0x8007052e.

Environment: The website is deployed on a Windows 2000 server.

Any help and comments would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The account under which your application is running (probably IIS pool account) does not have access to the file that you are trying to send. The error code `0x8007052e` means:

```
Error code: (HRESULT) 0x8007052e (2147943726) - Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

In the future you can check the error code using for instance cdb command (cdb is a part of the freely available Windows Debugging Tools):

```
cdb notepad.exe
```

And then after it has started:

```
0:000> !error  0x8007052e
Error code: (HRESULT) 0x8007052e (2147943726) - Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password.
```

Hope it helps :)